# Make C# Program to windows embadded professional 6.5

Tags: c#, windows, frameworks, pocketpc

I would like to create a C # program to be inserted into a Falcon X3 (that is a barcod with a touch display with installed windows embedded professional 6.5) but when I've copy the project into device and I've tried to open this file it said that i have to install framework compact 2.0. So I download this file from microsoft but the size is not accepted by device. I read that there is cab file that are supported by this device but i don't find anything about this size to istall windows framework in cab size. I Have a Question, what can i do to make a program for this device?

Comment: Show us what you have implemented?

Comment: Now before making programs i want to show in device the easy program : "Hello World".